# Check a generic class contained in a java.util.List

Tags: java, generics

I have two classes as below:

```
Class#1    
public class Vert<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Comparable<Vert<T>> {
    protected T data;

    public Vert(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Vert<T> other) {
        return data.compareTo(other.data);
    }
}

Class#2
public class Edge implements Comparable<Edge> {
    protected int data;

    public Edge(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Edge o) {
        return data - o.data;
    }
}
```

And a class which contains a list of these two classes:

```
Class#3
public class Comp {
    private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";
    private final int NUM_VERTEX;
    private final int NUM_EDGES;
    private List<Vert<Integer>> vertList = new ArrayList<Vert<Integer>>();
    private List<Edge> edgeList = new ArrayList<Edge>();

    public Comp(InputStream in) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in, CHARSET);
        NUM_VERTEX = scanner.nextInt();
        NUM_EDGES = scanner.nextInt();

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] vertices = line.split(" ");
            int v1 = Integer.parseInt(vertices[0]);
            int v2 = Integer.parseInt(vertices[1]);
            Vert<Integer> vert1 = new Vert<Integer>(v1);
            Vert<Integer> vert2 = new Vert<Integer>(v2);
            Edge e = new Edge(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

            ////////////// error here ////////////////
            if (vertList.contains(vert1)) {

            }
        }
    }

    /////////////// method 1 ///////////////////
    public boolean hasV(Vert<Integer> v) {
        return vertList.contains(v);
    }

    /////////////// method 2 ///////////////////
    public boolean hasEdge(Edge edge) {
        return edgeList.contains(edge);
    }
}
```

Method 2 decorated above returns value according to `edgeList` containing the edge.
However, Method 1 decorated above gives a compilation error that `contains` is not defined.
I am learning type safety and generics but unable to figure what's wrong here as List interface defines the method `contains` in its API.

[edit] I've edited the source to complete example. The exact error thrown is:
`Cannot resolve method contains`.

Comment: `private List<Node<Integer>> vertList = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();`: this can't possibly compile. You want `private List<Node<Integer>> vertList = new ArrayList<Node<Integer>>();`, or simply `private List<Node<Integer>> vertList = new ArrayList<>();`.

Comment: Fixed the typo in the question.

Comment: If I override ``compareTo`` methods where needed and add a dummy ``Node<T>`` class, it compiles. Are you sure that you have a compilation problem ?

Comment: Once I remove the `...`and the `implement Comparable...` to make your code compile, everything compiles fine. Post a complete example reproducing the error. And post the exact and complete error message you get.

Comment: I get the same result as kraal and JB. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Can you add the error message you're seeing?

Comment: Edited the question with complete example. The exact error thrown is: `Cannot resolve method contains`.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense that you would have that error messages coming from this code, but how is a `List<Vert<Integer>>` ever going to contain a `Node<Integer>`? That's just going to return false. Also, compile-time error messages aren't "thrown".

Comment: @DavidConrad I'm extremely sorry. I had code opened in two windows, pasted half from one and rest from other. I've updated the question now. Extremely sorry for wasting everyone's time with incorrect OP.

Comment: Once again, you posted code that can't possibly compile, and failed to read and post the error messages. Read the error messages: they're extremely clear: `cannot find symbol - variable NUM_VERTEX`, `cannot find symbol - variable NUM_EDGES`, `variable v1 is already defined`, `variable v2 is already defined`.

Comment: And here you go again. The posted code has one compilation error. It says: `Error:(30, 38) java: ')' expected`.

Comment: I give up.....made a fool out of myself. Need to sleep right now!!

Comment: Promise to self: Always post questions with eyes and brains open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making mistake here. `v1` has two datatypes i.e. `int` and `Vert<Integer>` and this is not possible in a same scope.

Try this

Class#3

```
public class Comp {
    private List<Vert<Integer>> vertList = new ArrayList<Vert<Integer>>();
    private List<Edge> edgeList = new ArrayList<Edge>();

    public Comp(InputStream in) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in, CHARSET);
        NUM_VERTEX = scanner.nextInt();
        NUM_EDGES = scanner.nextInt();

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] vertices = line.split(" ");
            int v1 = Integer.parseInt(vertices[0]);
            int v2 = Integer.parseInt(vertices[1]);
            Vert<Integer> vert1 = new Vert<Integer>(v1); // Change variable name v1 to vert1
            Vert<Integer> vert2 = new Vert<Integer>(v2); // Change variable name v2 to vert2
            Edge e = new Edge(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

            if (vertList.contains(vert1) { // Change variable name v1 to vert1

            }
        }
    }

    /////////////// method 1 ///////////////////
    public boolean hasV(Vert<Integer> v) {
        return vertList.contains(v);
    }

    /////////////// method 2 ///////////////////
    public boolean hasEdge(Edge edge) {
        return edgeList.contains(edge);
    }
}
```

Comment: This update#2 now makes Vert class npt compile. It gives the error "Unexpected token" in update#2

Comment: Now I don't see a difference between my class#3 and the solution. :-/

Comment: Comments added where I made changes.

Comment: I think I better sleep now. Even after multiple edits to my question, I still managed to post it wrong. Editing the question one last time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65419/discussion-between-junaid-and-gashu).